# how to retrieve login status while using offline_access

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-oauth

I'm facing a little problem because of the offline_access permission I'm requesting for my website.

I'm using the code that is given in the documentation in order to define if someone is logged or not :

```
 if ($user) {
    try {
       // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
       $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
      }
 }
```

But as I have an offline access, it seems that I'm always having a value for $user. So how can i log out someone from my website ?

Is there any way to retrieve a status via the php SDK ?

Thanks for the help,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

In PHP try using GetLogoutUrl and sending the user there.  You can also call the JS FB.logout() call from client-side.  If you want to remove the app from the user, call HTTP delete to `me/permissions`.

Comment: in fact i have no problem to logout a user. I'm indeed calling the JS FB.logout() on my logout button. when i click my logout button, i'm effectively logged out from facebook. But as i'm requesting the offline_access permission ... i'm always receiving from facebook an userid and the $userprofile. So the condition from the PHP is always true.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you asked: "So how can i log out someone from my website ? " for this question.